# Both are almost same codes for House Robber III in leetcode but one is time limit exceed code whereas other is perfect solution to the question

Tags: python

The correct code is

```
class Solution:
    def rob(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        def dfs(root):
            if not root:
                return [0,0]
            leftpair=dfs(root.left)
            rightpair=dfs(root.right)
            withroot=root.val+leftpair[1]+rightpair[1]
            withoutroot=max(leftpair)+max(rightpair)
            return [withroot,withoutroot]
                
        
        return max(dfs(root))
```

The code which is leading to time limit exceeded error in leetcode is

```
class Solution:
    def rob(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        def dfs(root):
            if not root:
                return [0,0]
            
            left=root.val+dfs(root.left)[1]+dfs(root.right)[1]
            right=max(dfs(root.left))+max(dfs(root.right))
            return [left,right]
                
        return max(dfs(root))
```

I don't think there is any difference in time complexities of above two code. Can someone help me with this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version of `dfs` calls itself recursively twice, saving the results and reusing them.  Here are the two recursive calls:

```
leftpair=dfs(root.left)
rightpair=dfs(root.right)
```

The second version of `dfs` calls itself recursively four times.  Here are the four recursive calls, embedded in expressions:

```
left=root.val+dfs(root.left)[1]+dfs(root.right)[1]
right=max(dfs(root.left))+max(dfs(root.right))
```

As you can see, rather than reusing the results of the recursive calls, it instead repeats the calls (twice with `root.left` and twice with `root.right`).  Understandably, this results in a significantly longer tuntime.